# JTable updating in run time

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Is there a way to update a JTable during run time and without using the constructor?

I have a JTable that I have already added to my JPanel but I want to be able to define the columns and data at a later point in the code instead of immediately in the constructor method, is there a way to do this?

```
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
JTable table = new JTable();
jp.add(table);
```

Also, is there a way to convert a 2 dimensional array list into a 2 dimensional object array so I can use it in the JTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to be able to define the columns and data at a later point in the code instead of immediately in the constructor method, is there a way to do this?

Use a [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) To manage the data. See the "default" implementation [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html). At any time you can use `JTable#setModel` and pass new `TableModel`.

```
JTable table = new JTable();
...
// Some time later
String[] headers = ...
Object[][] data = ...
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
table.setModel(model);
```

Or you can create the table with the model, and at whatever time, call the model's methods, like (in the case of `DefaultTableModel`), `setColumnIdentifiers`, `addRow`, `setDataVector`

```
String[] headers = ...
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(headers, 0);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
...
// Some time later
Object[] row = ...
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
model.addRow(row);
String[] newHeaders = ...
model.setColumnIdentifiers(newHeaders);
```

> "Also, is there a way to convert a dimensional array list into a 2 dimensional object array so I can use it in the JTable?"

I've never heard the term "dimensional array list". But if you want to add an `ArrayList<String>` as a row, you can simply call `list.toArray` and add a row to the `DefaultTableModel`. If it's an `ArrayList<YourType>`, you may need to create a custom table model implementation. (See the link below)

**See for more info:**

- [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- [DefaultTableModel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)
- [Creating a TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Comment: Sorry, I meant converting something like an ArrayList<List<Integer>> into an object[][], for purposes of putting it into the JTable. (and I meant to say "2 dimensional array list", missed the 2, still not sure if that's an actual term though).

Comment: You can use `Vector<Vector<Integer>>`, and use `DefaultTableModel.setDataVector(...)`. `Vector` works like `ArrayList`. It's dynamic with `add` method.

Comment: OK I tried your method with the DefaultTableModel and it seems to work fine thanks. I want to ask another question, is it possible to have something in the same JTable that displays on the side of the table (e.g. the row number)? I made an image trying to explain what I want. http://i.imgur.com/iaAfDfn.jpg Basically similar to how we have headers for the column names, I want something where I can put row names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set the table's contents at runtime.  see [`JTable.setModel(TableModel)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setModel(javax.swing.table.TableModel))

> Also, is there a way to convert a dimensional array list into a 2
>   dimensional object array so I can use it in the JTable?

I'm not sure what you mean by "dimensional array list" but you can either convert the data structure to a standard [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) implementation like DefaultTableModel , or write a wrapper class that implements the `TableModel` interface. The wrapper class would read data directly from your data structure and expose its elements to the `JTable` via the methods defined in `TableModel`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addRow` method of `DefaultTableModel` to add data to table, at runtime. And use `fireTableDataChanged` to notify your `JTable` to update it's UI. [Document here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: *"And use fireTableDataChanged"* - No never don't.  The `fireTableXxx` methods should never be used outside of the model itself, it's the responsibility of the model to make the decisions about when it will make notifications of changes